# Fade Image Entering UITableView Edit Mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell class and each cell has a UIImageView which I have given it.

All I want to do is fade out this image when entering edit mode and fade it back in when exiting edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write following method in your custome cell class

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
     [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
     if (editing) {
   PUT YOUR fade animation code here
     }
```

}

Comment: This is working, well, thanks, but is there a way to differentiate between pressing the edit button and swiping to delete? As I only need to do this when tapping the edit button, swiping doesn't cause issues.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010926/differentiate-between-uitableview-editing-states

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//detect editing mode
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleRows) { // loop through the visible cells and animate their imageViews

         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 delay:0
                 animations: ^{ cell.imageView.alpha = 0.5; }
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished) { cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0; }
         }];
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this method part of UITableView or UITableViewCell? I can't find any info on it anywhere.

Comment: The previous method I actually made up, this method (in its full form should be documented under UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. You only reference to `didEnterEditingMode`, which I assume you made up? Which method is it that is documented?

Comment: I have updated the code with a documented method. The method is `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`