# Differentiate Between UITableView Editing States?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have been looking at trying to differentiate between editing states in my UITableView.

I need to call a method only when in editing mode after tapping the edit button, so when you get your cell slide in and you see the little circular delete icons but NOT when the user swipes to delete.

Is there anyway I can differentiate between the two?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Solution thanks to Rodrigo

Both each cell and the entire tableview has an 'editing' BOOL value, so I loop through all the cells and if more than one of them is editing then we know the whole table is (the user tapped the edit button), however if only one is editing then we know that the user has swiped a cell, editing that individual one, this lets me deal with each editing state individually!

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];


    int i = 0;
    //When editing loop through cells and hide status image so it doesn't block delete controls. Fade back in when done editing.
    for (customGuestCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) 
    { 
        if (cell.isEditing) {
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    if (i > 1) 
    {
        for (customGuestCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) 
        { 
            if (editing) 
            {
                // loop through the visible cells and animate their imageViews
                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
                cell.statusImg.alpha = 0;
                [UIView commitAnimations];
            } 
        }
    }
    else if (!editing) 
    {
        for (customGuestCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) 
        { 
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
            cell.statusImg.alpha = 1.0;
            [UIView commitAnimations];            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO this does not work: When in regular editing mode (all cells editable) then the first cell thinks it is in "swipe on delete mode".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are one strategy, I do not test now, but maybe work.

You can set the UITableView to be in editing mode and test with `isEditing` function. But the cell have the same `isEditing`. So you can check if only one cell is in editing state or all the UITableView.

Check if when you set one cell to be in editing state, the UITableView change to editing state at all.

Comment: Ahh, really nice idea, but I have given is a try and haven't managed to get it working this way.

Comment: Got this solution working, thanks! I have posted how I got around it in my OP.

Answer (score 5):

Even if this post is quite old, the following might be helpful to others:

If you implement the following delegate messages:
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

and

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

These methods will be called when editing a single line. `-[UIViewController setEditing:animated:]` will then only get called when the user hits the edit button.

Comment: This is still helpful for me in 2019. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The solution I chose was to override the action for the edit button to a custom method, say editBtnTapped.  In this method I set a variable editButtonPressed, and then, because we overrode the the edit button's action, manually call setEditing:animated:.

In viewDidLoad:

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(editBtnPressed)];
```

And then the new action method:

```
- (IBAction) editBtnPressed
{
  if ([self isEditing]) 
  {
    self.editButtonPressed = NO;
    [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
  }
  else  
  {
    self.editButtonPressed = YES;
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
  }
}
```

Now in setEditing:animated: I check the editButtonPressed flag to determine if I'm in there because of an Edit button press or a simple user swipe.  If I'm there due to the Edit button, I add the cell; otherwise I don't.

Keep in mind you may need the flag elsewhere, (e.g. numberOfRowsInSection).

Hope this alternative helps.

Regards,

--John

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way I have found to do this is to maintain a private flag `inEditMode` and toggle this flag in `setEditing:animated`. Then use `inEditMode` rather than `isEditing` to check if the table is in edit mode or not.

Comment: Sorry there isn't a great deal of info here, thanks for answering though and could you expand please? How exactly do you use your `inEditMode` BOOL to differentiate the edit modes?

Comment: Unlike `isEditing`, this `inEditMode` is *only* `YES` if the table is "really" in editing mode (that is, not through a single swipe action).